# Change element class name based on URL

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

So I have several elements (`td`s of a table). I want to change the style of them based on the URL you are currently on. Having the below pages:

```
http:\\domain\site\welcome.html
http:\\domain\site\press.html
http:\\domain\site\contact.html
```

There is a common part, a `table` and I need to change the style of the `td`s.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="welcome" class="default">Welcome</td>
        <td id="press" class="default">Press</td>
        <td id="contact" class="default">Contact</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.default {
//settings
}
.current {
//settings
}
```

So basically if the URL contains string `welcome` then I need `class` of `td` having `id=welcome` to be `current`. I tried the below but it does nothing.

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
$( document ).ready(
    function() {
    if (document.URL.indexOf("welcome") > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("welcome").className = "current";
    }
    else if (document.URL.indexOf("press") > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("press").className = "current";
    }
    else if (document.URL.indexOf("contact") > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("contact").className = "current";
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Because I only need that. The rest should remain default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(
    function() {
if (document.URL.indexOf("welcome") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById("welcome").className = "current";
}
else if (document.URL.indexOf("press") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById("press").className = "current";
}
else if (document.URL.indexOf("contact") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById("contact").className = "current";
}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `src` to `<script>` so your code is ignored. change it to this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     /* rest of code */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add jquery lib and add below code after html in script tag 
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
function getPageName(url) {
var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
var filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0]; 
return filename;                                    
}
var a = getPageName(pathname); $( "#"+a ).addClass( "current" );
```